# My hardest rebus yet! Guess the theme and solve!

Tags: wordplay, rebus

You must guess the common theme and then solve each rebus (no explanation required). Some might be very straightforward, but others require a little more thinking.

[image]

Happy St. Patrick's Day, enjoy!

Comment: Tbh, I was unsure of what the last part of D represents, is it somehow related to 2?

Comment: Yes, it is Russian for two. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Full answer

Common theme:

> Types of Dogs

A:

> Cocker Spaniel - combination of cock, span and yule.

B:

> German Shepherd - combination of Germany and shepherd

C:

> Poodle - combination of Poo and doll

D:

> Chihuahua - combination of chi (character) and waa (said by Waluigi)

E:

> Golden retriever - since the bridge is called the Golden gate, and the women is a weaver

F:

> Husky - since the pictures are of a corn husk and Euler's number, e

G:

> Corgi - combination of core and ghee

H:

> Pit bull - from @thecoder16, combination of Pit (Kid Icarus) and a bull

I:

> Beagle - combination of a bee and a gull

Comment: They are all right so far, except for H. Keep up the good work! :)

Comment: just did H now :)

Comment: @thecoder16 Darn, I was so close to getting it :D. I knew it was Icarus from Nintendo, but I wasn't sure how it related to a bull

Comment: Good job and partial credit to @thecoder16 ! :)

Comment: @MicCrozier Thanks, great Rebus. Got excited as soon as I found out the common theme, and couldn't stop.

Comment: Nice job!, I got stuck on C trying to figure a way for that baby to somehow be a "tzu"...

Answer (score 6):

Another partial answer.

H:

> Pit bull

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely correct